# How to count file of category in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 table data:

db_category: 
+idcategory
+name 
db_book:
+ idbook
+ name
+ idcategory

Now I want show count of book by category, explample:
  book 1 : 2 file
  book 2 : 2 file
Please help me, thanks

Comment: Please make clear your question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.idcategory, COUNT(*) as count FROM  
    FROM db_category a, db_book b
    WHERE a.idcategory = b.idcategory' 
    GROUP BY  a.idcategory;
```